# No encuentro el error en mi código en PHP

Tags: php, base-de-datos, web, backend

estoy intentando crear un formulario de registro a una página web y me está saliendo un error que no consigo arreglar.

```
<?php

$nombre = $_POST["NOMBRE"]; 
$apellido1 = $_POST["APELLIDO1"];
$apellido2 = $_POST["APELLIDO2"];
$email = $_POST["EMAIL"];
$login = $_POST["LOGIN"];
$userpassword = $_POST["PASSWORD"];

// Validación adicional en PHP
if (empty($nombre) || empty($apellido1) || empty($apellido2) || empty($email) || empty($login) || empty($userpassword)) {
    die("Por favor, completa todos los campos.");
}

// Validación de formato de correo electrónico
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    die("El formato del correo electrónico no es válido.");        
}

// Validación de longitud de contraseña
if (strlen($userpassword) < 4 || strlen($userpassword) > 8) {
    die("La contraseña debe tener entre 4 y 8 caracteres.");
}

// Conexión a la base de datos
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "registros";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

   // Verificar si el correo electrónico ya existe en la base de datos
   $sql = "SELECT ID FROM registros WHERE EMAIL = '$email'";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
       die("El correo electrónico ya está registrado. Por favor, utiliza otro correo electrónico.");
   }

// Insertar los datos en la base de datos
$sql = "INSERT INTO registros (NOMBRE, APELLIDO1, APELLIDO2, EMAIL, LOGIN, PASSWORD) VALUES ('$nombre', '$apellido1', '$apellido2', '$email', '$login', '$userpassword')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Registro completado con éxito";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM registros";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<h2>Usuarios registrados</h2>";
    echo "<ul>";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<li>" . $row["NOMBRE"] . " " . $row["APELLIDO1"] . " " . $row["APELLIDO2"] . "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
} else {
    echo "No hay usuarios registrados.";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

El error en cuestión es el siguiente:

> 8. { die("La contraseña debe tener entre 4 y 8 caracteres."); } // Conexión a la base de datos $servername = "localhost"; $username = "root"; $password = ""; $dbname = "registros"; $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); if ($conn->connect_error) { die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); } // Verificar si el correo electrónico ya existe en la base de datos $sql = "SELECT ID FROM registros WHERE EMAIL = '$email'"; $result = $conn->query($sql); if ($result->num_rows > 0) { die("El correo electrónico ya está registrado. Por favor, utiliza otro correo electrónico."); } // Insertar los datos en la base de datos $sql = "INSERT INTO registros (NOMBRE, APELLIDO1, APELLIDO2, EMAIL, LOGIN, PASSWORD) VALUES ('$nombre', '$apellido1', '$apellido2', '$email', '$login', '$userpassword')"; if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) { echo "Registro completado con éxito"; } else { echo "Error: " . $sql . "
>    " . $conn->error; } $conn->close(); $sql = "SELECT * FROM registros"; $result = $conn->query($sql); if ($result->num_rows > 0) { echo "
>    Usuarios registrados
>    "; echo "
>
>    "; while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { echo "
>    " . $row["NOMBRE"] . " " . $row["APELLIDO1"] . " " . $row["APELLIDO2"] . "
>    "; } echo "
>
> "; } else { echo "No hay usuarios registrados."; } $conn->close(); ?>

¿Me podríais ayudar?

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Puedes añadir que error te da? En la parte donde dices que aparece un error, tienes puesto otra vez el codigo

Comment: Revisa los datos que te llegan con `print_r['$_POST']; die();`, antes de hacer las validaciones. Puede ser que te esté llegando un dato erróneo o se está interrumpiendo el código por algún error tipográfico. Por lo que muestras en el error, podría ser en la variable `$userpassword`.

Comment: Eso no parece un error, si no que la página está imprimiendo el mismo código que has escrito. Esto es casi siempre porque (1) No está encendido el webserver, (2) el proyecto no está dentro del directorio htdocs, www, wwwroot, etc, dependiendo de tu webserver. (3) Otra razón puede ser usar rutas absolutas en el `form action=""`. Como ningún intérprete está procesando el PHP, este será enviado directamente a la salida.

Comment: El error que me da es justamente que se reproduce el código, he copiado y pegado literalmente lo que ocurre al clicar en "enviar" @Jakala

Comment: La variable `$userpassword` la puse intentando evitar que saliese el error (de poco sirvió), ya que la variable `$password` ya estaba siendo empleada anteriormente. En cuanto al ´print_r['$_POST']; die();´, no me ha proporcionado ninguna información. @DjCrazy

Comment: En cuanto a las posibilidades que me dices, (1) lo he comprobado y sí que estaba encendido, (2) el proyecto sí que estaba en el directorio correspondiente y (3) había utilizado ´form method="POST" action="formulario.php"´, no sé si este sería correcto o no (todavía soy muy nueva en esto, perdón) @aeportugal